# MongoDB find in sub-document of a sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document structure with a reference to another document that itself references an additional document: `A->B` `B->C`.

I'm trying to perform a `find` operation on `A` by the `_id` of the document `C`, but I can't find a way of executing this query.

I have tried some approaches, but none it's wokring:

```json
{
  "B.C": {"$in": ["some mongo IDs"]}
}
```

```json
{
  "B.C._id": {"$in": ["some mongo IDs"]}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The structure of your documents is not clear. Is this one nested document in one collection (de-normalized, as is the best practice for document DBs) or more than one document in one or more collection with references to _id of the other documents (normalized, as is the best practice for relation DBs).

Comment: A contains a reference by _id to B and B contains a reference by _id to C. So I do populate to get all the information from my find queries

Comment: Use MongoDB aggregation pipeline:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

The way to find that is to use aggregation, starting from the information you have and working toward the information you want.

From the description, in the database the A documents only contain the B._id values, and B documents contain only the C._id values.

Since the value you have that you want to base the query on is C._id, you should start the query in either B or C.

If you do not need to return any fields from the C document, you can skip that collection, and query for B documents that contain the desired C._id, and they query A for documents that contain any of the discovered B._id values.

An aggregation pipeline for that might look something like:

```
B.aggregate([
  {$match: {"C": {"$in": ["some mongo IDs"]}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "A",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "B",
      as: "Adocs"
  }},
  {$unwind: "$Adocs"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$Adocs"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yq6H8NhIPoK)

If you need to make sure there are no duplicates, add these stages before the replaceRoot:

```
  {$group:{_id:null, Adocs:{$addToSet:"$Adocs"}}},
  {$unwind: "$Adocs"},
```

Comment: This looks like a valid alternative. However, I'm trying to achieve the result using exclusively find queries. I'm building some REST API and would like to pass a query object to the get-all route and return the result of the find query. It might be the case that it is not possible without changing the structure of my documents.